# Problems with VBox Guest Additions on Kubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, guest-additions

After Kubuntu installation I wanted to install Guset Additions (GA).
During this process I was informed that my system lack of `make`, `gcc` and appropriate `headers` but graphics module build without problems and after reboot everything works fine (with scaling guest system window).

Unfortunately shared folders didn't work so I install missing tools:

`` sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install build-essentials linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms ``

(more or less - this is how I remembered it :))

I also tried:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
sudo m-a prepare`

with same result.

Then I run GA installation one more time and everything ends with **success**.
After reboot desktop looked nice, but when I pointed taskbar with my mouse it "jumps out" below the screen. Any attempt to open some window e.g. console gives no result. It is like I can see only top left corner of my desktop but without any window if it really opens.

I thought this is Kubuntu 15.10 beta-1 fault but on stable Kubuntu 15.04 things looks same.

What I did wrong? I also use Xubuntu and I never have problems like this.
I really appreciate any help and I am very sorry for my terrible english

Answer (score 2):

The Problem with non shown windows and Taskbar is related to a a VirtualBox Setting Guest Setting. If you enable 3D-Acceleration under Virtualbox Display Settings you have this problem.

Just a remark of installing the guest additions. You can easily install them over the additional driver installer under kde settings.
So you don't need to install all the make gcc etc. and install it manually over the iso.